# Is it possible to substitute a token in markdown?

Tags: python, regex, coffeescript, markdown

I am using regex in Python to pull comments, formatted with Markdown, from a CoffeeScript file. CS uses ### as the start and end markers for multiline comments. This conflicts with the markdown formatting because # is used to denote a header class. Is it be possible make Markdown interpret the % or ^ or some other character as the header class token?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a matter of searching for '#' characters in your markdown library and replacing the appropriate one with the character of your choice?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I modify the Python Markdown source just for this task?

Comment: Can you think of an alternative? You seem to need your own special flavor of markdown, why not go for it?

Comment: I was hoping to find some an for overriding the default behavior of the library programmatically. I'm still digging through the source to see if that is possible, but I haven't found anything quite yet.

Comment: Are `###` in the CoffeeScript file actually used to denote headers? If not, why wouldn't you filter them out (via regex) before feeding the comments to the Markdown library?

Comment: @Helgi ### is used to denote the beginning and end of a comment. What is causing a problem is that if a comment happens to contain another # before the closing, the actual CS script fails to compile into JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to override many elements of Python Markdown by taking advantage of the `markdown.extensions.Extension` class. After a little digging and experimenting I got this to work by writing a custom header parser which extended the generic BlockParser.

Essentially it looks something like this

```
class CustomHeaderParser( BlockParser )
    def run( params )
        # implementation

class CustomExtension( Extension )
    def extendMarkdown( self, md, md_globals )
        md.parser.blockprocessor.add( 'custom_header_parser', CustomHeaderParser(md.parser), '<hashheader' )
        md.registerExtension( self )


markdown_parser = markdown.Markdown( extensions=[ CaretHeaderExtension() ] )
markdown_parser.convert( markdown_text )
```

About half way through researching this I also found another, less desirable, work around. There are two types of header styles that markdown understands Setext and atx. Setext uses ==== and ----- on the line below the text to provide two header levels h1 and h2.

Comment: What do setext and atx stand for?